# Ruby is returning actual newlines instead of \n

Tags: ruby

I have a file `"Foo.md"`, which contains three lines:

```
Foo

Bar
```

I want `File.read("Foo.md")` to return `"Foo\n\nBar"` It does this when I run it from irb in the Terminal, but when I run it from a script such as

```
content = File.read('Foo.md')
puts content
```

it returns with the lines converted to actual returns. I need that variable as a single line for what comes next in my script.

To be clear: I'm not interested in changing the number of lines, just debugging to make sure the variable `content` is being passed as a single line.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Foo\n\n\nBar\n"?

Comment: Do you want to emulate the behavior of irb? Or are you doing this because you want to escape special characters? That is, do you want to look at the variable for debugging purposes, or do you just want to put everything on one line?

Comment: Thanks everyone so far. Just to be totally clear: file has three lines, so it is actually "Foo\n\nBar". But the exact number of "\n"s is not the issue: as @Schwern guesses, I'm trying to look at the variable for debugging and to make sure it's passed correctly to the next section of the script, which requires it be a single string with no spaces.

Comment: @craigeley Rather than eyeballing it, would it be better to add code that checks its a string with no spaces?

Comment: @Schwern - Sure. The important thing here is that variable is created without new lines, as in, with "/n"s in place of them.

This discussion is interesting, though, and now I feel like I have more fundamental questions about how File.read works, but that's for another day. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still reading `"Foo\n\n\nBar"`. However, `puts` interprets the special characters.

You can use [`String#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-inspect):

```
puts content.inspect # => "Foo\n\n\nBar"
```

Comment: `puts` doesn't interpret the characters, `inspect` encodes them.

Comment: This is not safe. It will put it in quotes. It will also do the wrong thing if the object is not a String object, it will show the class. The format of [`Object.inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect) should not be relied upon to be anything but human readable. `inspect`'s behavior can be overridden.

Comment: @Schwern How can the result of reading a file not be a string object?

Comment: @muistooshort, you can look at it that way too.

Comment: @sawa For this exact piece of code it is *probably* safe for the current version of Ruby. As a general purpose technique for escaping special characters it is not. You're handing the OP a gun without explaining the safety rules.

Comment: @Schwern, so your argument for downvoting is that if you pass it something, which you shouldn't pass, you will get a strange result and that if someone arbitrary monkey patches the core string class it might not work?

Comment: @ndn My argument is the OP is going to use this technique for escaping special characters on a string-like that doesn't come from a file and not understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Schwern This is an answer to the OP's question, it is not meant to be  a general purpose technique for escaping special characters, which only exists in your imagination.

Comment: @sawa That's A) very lazy to limit the answer to one that only works for the exact details of the question, B) might break in a future version and C) should be made extremely clear to the OP who is obviously not experienced to know that.

Comment: @ndn By the way, I had to downvote your answer because you faked the result.

Comment: @Schwern, I still don't get your point. Can you give me an example where `puts any_string.inspect` wouldn't do exactly what OP wants?

Comment: @sawa, could you elaborate? What do you mean by fake the result?

Comment: @ndn `ruby -e 'require "uri"; string = URI("http://example.com"); puts string; puts string.inspect'`

Comment: @Schwern, um... you do realize that `string` here is not a `String`?

Comment: @ndn Yes, it's a thing that acts like a string and it could be returned by a method that returns a "string". That's the whole point of duck typing. Why tempt fate with `inspect`, and get the wrong format because of the quotes, when `thing.to_s.gsub` works without caveats?

Comment: @Schwern, by that logic I shouldn't use any of the `Array`'s method in my answers because someone might want to use them for something that acts like an array, but implements some methods to do completely different things. And no, `URI::HTTP` is not intended to be a sort of string, it can just be visualized as a string...

Comment: @ndn No, those overrides would be a violation of the `Array` interface and considered bugs. You're violating `Object.inspect`'s interface by using it *outside its defined behavior*. It only guarantees a "*human readable representation*". The docs encourage that "*user defined classes should override this method to provide a better representation of obj*" [`String.inspect` overrides the default behavior](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-inspect), it is normally "*object’s class name, an encoding of the object id, and a list of the instance variables and their values*".

Comment: @Schwern, in what way is that an argument? Lets say you have a hierarchy with `Animal`, `Dog < Animal`, `Cat < Animal`. And `Animal`s have `make_sound` method, which in `Dog` is implemented as `"bark"`. A person is asking me right now *how do I make a dog bark?*. I answer with `dog.make_sound`. And you say - no!, that is a terrible idea, because the default implementation of `make_sound` is `"grrrr"` and a `Cat` might implement an entirely different thing to! WHAT?

Comment: I think part of the disagreement here is I've interpreted the question as "how do I escape newlines" but it might also be "how do I emulate the behavior of `irb`". If it's the latter, this answer is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90827/discussion-between-schwern-and-ndn).

Comment: @ndn Convinced me it's not a problem because `String.inspect`'s format is well defined and "has a string representation" is not the same as "duck type String".

Comment: @sawa, if you were referring to the missing `\n` at the end - it wasn't intentional, I just copied the string from the question without giving it much thought. Another person has also noticed this and I accepted his edit.

Comment: @ndn Not only the end of the string. The difference was more substantial than that. And that does not change the fact that what you say is the result of your code is not what it really is. Now that your answer has been edited, you can see that it does not give what the OP wanted.

Comment: @sawa, I see it now. I won't change it as I will paradoxically be ripping off your answer. However, I'm not sure if the downvote is fair. The way I read it, he wants it the same way it appears in irb. In irb it will appear with 3 `\n`s. Maybe OP just mistakenly missed one `\n`.

Comment: Also the final `\n` wont appear if there is no new line at the end of the file...

Comment: Yes. That is the point. My emphasis is on the two versus three `\n`s in the middle rather than the one at the end of the string.

Comment: @sawa, I got you. My point was just that whether there should be 2 or 3 `\n`s is a little ambiguous. There is either a mistake in this statement *I want `File.read("Foo.md")` to return `"Foo\n\nBar"`* or in this statement *It does this when I run it from irb* and we don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

```
str =
"Foo


Bar"
  #=> "Foo\n\n\nBar"
```

You could also do this:

```
str.gsub(/\n{3,}/,"\n\n")
  #=> "Foo\\nnBar"
```

Comment: But the OP wants two `\n`s.

Comment: Thanks, @sawa, missed that. Too bad, as I don't often get a chance to use `squeeze`.

Answer (score 1):

It might help you visualize what is happening by meditating on this:

```
str = <<EOT
Foo


Bar
EOT
```

`str`'s contents look like:

```
str # => "Foo\n\n\nBar\n"
```

Inspecting it escapes the backslashes for a visual representation, but it's *NOT* what you'd want to use when creating a string with embedded line-ends. You'd want to define it as it's shown above.

```
str.inspect # => "\"Foo\\n\\n\\nBar\\n\""
```

`inspect` output varies when viewed in IRB vs. the console. Here's what you'd see in the console:

```
ruby -e 'puts "\n"; puts "\n".inspect'

"\n"
```

Printing `str` to the console:

```
puts str
# >> Foo
# >> 
# >> 
# >> Bar
```